# TensorFlow : failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE

Tags: windows, tensorflow, cudnn

**My test :**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()`
```

**Error :**

c:\l\work\tensorflow-1.1.0\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:405]

failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE

-> but "/cpu:0" works fine

**Config :**

nvidia-smi :
[image]

- CUDA Version 9.1
- tensorflow-1.1.0
- Windows 10
- cudnn64_7.dll (installed in C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin)
- Only tensorflow-gpu is installed in my Conda environment

Why can't Tensorflow detect my GPU ?

Comment: If you're using Tensorflow 1.1 from the prebuild binaries, you need CUDA 8 and cuDNN 5.1. Did you build this yourself?

Comment: I have updated Tensorflow to v1.5. The error message disappeared but it is still using my CPU instead of my GPU. Do you what could be the reason?

Comment: You installed via pip "tensorflow" instead of "tensorflow-gpu" perhaps?

Comment: no, tensorflow-gpu is installed (only)

Comment: Now I'm on :
- Tensorflow-gpu 1.6
- CUDA 9.0
- Cudnn 7.0
Still : failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE

Comment: I have given more details there : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16860

Comment: Wait, in the issue you have `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"`. ow many GPUs do you have on your system? The screenshot only shows one, with device id `0`...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue was solved [on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16860). This error message will be shown if you set an invalid value for the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable, e.g. when you only have a single GPU (which has ID `0`) and set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` or `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`.

Comment: Seems to be also be happening with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1, which tells it to not use GPU. Tensorflow 2.4.1.

Answer (score 37):

The true answer is to add following line of code:

```py
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"
```

Comment: Thank you. Funny enough this solution helped even when explicit "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python ..." did not work.

Comment: So many places say to use "-1" to ignore GPU, but that just causes these error messages. Setting to zero makes sense, and it works (go figure)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Colab, it could be that your runtime is not GPU. Click the “Runtime” dropdown menu. Select “Change runtime type”. Now select GPU.